# Arithmetic operation in MySQL through Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, addition, cumulative-sum

I have a table t1 which have a column Marks in this column values are 10, 20, 30, 40.

Now I want to use a procedure to get this result:

Marks     Total_Marks

10            10

20            30

30            60

40            100

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE Total_Marks ( In Num Int(4) )
Begin

Declare Mark Int(4);
Declare Add_M Int(4);
DECLARE NO_MORE_ROWS  BOOLEAN;

DECLARE DataCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Marks
FROM t1 where marks = Num;

DECLARE DataCursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT Sum(Marks) FROM t1;

OPEN DataCursor;
FETCH DataCursor INTO Mark;
CLOSE DataCursor;

OPEN DataCursor1;
READ_LOOP1: LOOP
FETCH DataCursor1 INTO Add_M;
IF NO_MORE_ROWS THEN
LEAVE READ_LOOP1;
END IF;
BEGIN
SET Add_M = SUM(Mark);
END;
END LOOP READ_LOOP1;
CLOSE dataCursor1;

SET NO_MORE_ROWS = FALSE;

end //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: does it have primary key like serial_no

Comment: @timus2001 no it not contain any primary key

Comment: and are those marks sorted on ascending order,can 2 rows have same marks?

Comment: @timus2001 yes 2 row have same marks my aim is just add previews total with current row mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a procedure at all, let alone cursors. But what you need, is a column that defines the order of the rows as mentioned in the comments.

```
create table foo (id int auto_increment primary key, bar int);
insert into foo(bar) values (10), (20), (30), (40);
```

In this example I introduced the column `id` for that matter. Or you can of course just order by your marks or whatever suits your needs.

```
select
bar
, @total := @total + bar as my_total
from
foo
, (select @total := 0) var_init
order by id
```

- see it working live in this <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f1582/1/0)</kbd>

As explanation, with this cross joined query

```
, (select @total := 0) var_init
```

we initialize our variable holding the running total `@total`. It's the same as writing

```
set @total = 0;
select
bar
, @total := @total + bar as my_total
from
foo
order by id;
```

The rest is self explaining I guess.

You can read more about these type of variables [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html).

**UPDATE (for completeness):**

Here are two other possibilities how to solve it without variables. Although I like variables usually better, cause in this one

```
select
t1.bar
, sum(t2.bar)
from
foo t1
inner join foo t2 on t1.id >= t2.id
group by t1.id;
```

you end up with a potentially huge temporary table, since you join every row to all previous rows and then calculate the sum.

And in this solution

```
select
bar
, (select sum(bar) from foo sf where sf.id <= foo.id) as my_total
from
foo;
```

you have a dependent subquery executed for each row. This is even worse than the previous solution.

I posted those just for completeness and if you really can't use variables (because of creating a view for example).